# popup return parameters to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site opens a popup when clicking a button, now, the user can click ok or cancel. If Ok, the form in the parent must be sent.

Parent:

```
<input class="boton" type="button" value="Ok" accesskey="O" onClick="openPopup(,'texto.','Do you want to continue?')"/>
```

function openPopup

```
function openPopup(button,textoAlert,subTextoAlert) {
 var html = ...
  "<input class='botonPopup' type='button' value='Cancel' accesskey='C' onclick=\"window.close('popup');\"/>" +
    "<input class='botonPopup' type='button' value='Ok' accesskey='O' onclick=\"window.close('popup'); return true;\"/>"
     popup = window.open('','', 'titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no, top=300, left=300, width=484, height=231');
  popup.document.write(html);
      ...
```

So, when button ok is clicked, I need to use this "true"

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use my [sysend.js library](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) to send message from popup to other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`parent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp) property to access the parent window (including DOM tree and globally accessible variables).

For example, `parent.document.getElementById('...').dostuff` or `parent.callback(true)`

You would add this to the `onclick` handler of your `input` elements in the popup window.

Example:

**Parent**

```
<script>
  function callback(choice) {
    alert(choice ? "User hit ok!" : "User hit cancel");
  }
</script>
<input class="boton" type="button" value="Ok" accesskey="O" onClick="openPopup(,'texto.','Do you want to continue?')"/>
```

**Popup**

```
function openPopup(button,textoAlert,subTextoAlert) {
 var html = ...
  "<input class='botonPopup' type='button' value='Cancel' accesskey='C' onclick=\"parent.callback(false); window.close('popup');\"/>" +
    "<input class='botonPopup' type='button' value='Ok' accesskey='O' onclick=\"parent.callback(true); window.close('popup');\"/>"
     popup = window.open('','', 'titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no, top=300, left=300, width=484, height=231');
  popup.document.write(html);
      ...
```